# Project using two different versions of SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, windows

I am a junior developer and about to get my feet wet in my first "real" project. However we are trying to figure out a way to set everything up as the current developer lives out of country.

I was told to install certain programs, subversion clients and SQL Server 2000.

It does not seem that SQL Server 2000 can be installed on Windows 7. Are there inherent issues with me developing in a higher version of SQL Server like 2005? Is there an issue with stored procedures that can not be properly translated from on SQL Server version to another?

Again, I'm fairly new at this; please let me know if this is just a bad idea, impossible and any other guidance you can provide.

Comment: you might want to think about upgrading production from MSSQL2000 to something newer that 2000.  It is somewhat outdated at this point.

Comment: I agree, but it's out of my hands at this point. I'm kind of in a pinch really trying to get my feet wet and this company just want's to drag theirs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many features in newer versions of MSSQL that were not there in 2000 (multi-row inserts, newer hashing algorithms, and VARCHAR(MAX) to name a few).  If you're using SQL Server Management Studio, it will not check these differences for you, even if you are connected to a SQL server 2000 database - it automatically uses 2008 rules for its syntax highlighting.  Because of this it's easy to accidentally write code that's not 2000-compatible.

As far as getting 2000 running, if you have the install disk for an older version of windows, you could run a VM (http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/) and install the database server there.  If your company has a separate development environment, you could create a copy of the production database to work off of as well.

Answer (score 2):

The newer versions of SQL server bring new language and database features, if you write something using a feature that is available in SQL 2005 and not 2000 i.e. PIVOT then when you try and promote this to live then it will just get a syntax error.

There is no translation, if you went back in time 11 years, you'd still speak English you'd just get an odd look if you talked about 'Tweeting'.

You can set the [database compatibility level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx) to an earlier version for the specific database you are working on. This will stop you using the more modern features.

Answer (score 1):

For the most part, you won't run into issues is you're simply running standard stored procedures and SQL statements.

However, there are several things that might not work properly if you're not in sync.  SQL2005 was a relatively major upgrade and instroduced quite a bit of new functionality.

I don't know what you've got for available resources - dollars, etc, but ***if you have an MSDN Subscription at a level that provides you access to operating systems***, then I would strongly recommend setting up a virual machine with an older version of Windows using your MSDN licenses, just to keep things on an even playing field.